# With Google Apps Admin SDK Directory API, how can I get authenticated user id?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace, google-directory-api

I have an authenticated user and am able to query for a [list of domain users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) using the google apis php client library.

However, it is unclear to me how I can retrieve the *currently logged in user*'s user id.  I tried using the `my_customer` alias which works for the list method, but when I try to do the [plain GET](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) request with user key as `my_customer`, it of course fails.

I know this must be something quite simple, but I cannot for the life of me find an answer in the documentation, so I'm pretty much reduced to guessing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your app to work as Google Apps marketplace app, you must  implement authentication using OAUTH2.

As a result you must have access to one of the following scopes which provide the APIs that get you the user Id :

- *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile* (deprecated) : Gain read-only access to basic profile information, including a user identifier, name, profile photo, profile URL, country, language, timezone, and birthdate.
- *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login* : If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me.